# Creating Broken Symlink

Tags: node.js, filesystems, symlink

Why is this creating a broken symlink?

```
var fs = require("fs")
fs.symlinkSync("./file.txt", "./empty-dir/symlink.txt", "file")
```

I can see the file in the dir via Finder or `fs.readdir` but the file cannot be read or opened.

> The operation can’t be completed because the original item for “symlink.txt” can’t be found.

[image]

If it matters I'm running io.js <strike>`v2.2.1`</strike> `v2.5.0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having absolute paths to the files fixes the issue.

```
var fs = require("fs")
var path = require("path")

fs.symlinkSync(path.resolve("./file.txt"), path.resolve("./empty-dir/symlink.txt"), "file")
```

Answer (score 0):

`./file.txt` is relative for `./empty-dir/symlink.txt`

Try use real path:

```
fs.symlinkSync(fs.realpathSync("./file.txt"), "./empty-dir/symlink.txt", "file")
```

Comment: Why are you using `fs.realpathSync()` and not just `path.resolve()`?